# How to check if window minimize animation is in progress (OSX)

Tags: macos, animation, minimize, window-managers

I want to get the window content of foreign windows in Mac OSX. All is working well, except that I want to pause the streaming when the target window is minimized. I worked out how to check for minimization using `kCGWindowIsOnscreen` from Core Graphics.

Now the problem: During the minimization animation the window is still considered Onscreen but obviously the content is utterly distorted. I'd like to pause the streaming just before the animation starts (i.e. when the animation is detected, no new frames should be recorded).

Is there a way to detect if the minimization animation is running? (Keep in mind that those are not my windows, i.e. I cannot simply intercept any onMinimize-events or alike)

Cheers,
Mind

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get position of path at time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622167/get-position-of-path-at-time)